# How can I get rid of the shadow when TabControl's DrawMode is OwnerDrawFixed?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Question:
How can I get rid of the shadow when TabControl's DrawMode is OwnerDrawFixed? I want to have the same appearance as before changing to OwnerDrawFixed.

Example code:

```
namespace Example {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
      tabControl1.DrawItem += DrawItem_TabControl;
    }

    // I can only change this method.
    private void DrawItem_TabControl(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
      TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
      TabPage tabPage = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];
      Brush foreBrush = tabControl.Focused && tabControl.SelectedIndex == e.Index ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;

      using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat()) {
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabPage.Text, tabPage.Font, foreBrush, e.Bounds, format);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

left:reallity, right:ideal
[image: reallity and ideal image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabControl.DrawItem not firing on user painted TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115321/tabcontrol-drawitem-not-firing-on-user-painted-tabcontrol)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: _e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, e.Bounds);_ What is this supposed to do? Also: Which shadow? Can you post an image?

Comment: @JohnB, Is there a way to do that without extending the control? And.. Reproducing the appearance using OnPaintBackground is a bit cumbersome. If it's possible, I want to know an easier way.

Comment: @TaW, Thanks, I added a Winforms tag. And 'e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, e.Bounds);' was unnecessary code for explanation.

Comment: If you're referring to the external border of the control, you need a Custom Control, override WndProc and define the inner rectangle offset on a [TCM_ADJUSTRECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcm-adjustrect) message. In practice, you need to offset the `RECT` structure passed by `lParam` by the difference of a `RECT` dimension and the current Control's Bounds. For example, the `Left` offset is `RECT.Left -= RECT.Left - [TabControl].Bounds.Left` etc. The `Top` offset is instead usually `-3`. Then call `Marshal.StructureToPtr([RECT], m.LParam, true);`.

Comment: Of course, you add to instead subtract from the `RECT.Right` and `RECT.Bottom` measures (`-1`, by design, as almost everywhere else).

Comment: @Jime: Actually he shows a 3d border for both the control body and the tabs. The link seems to be an 'easier' solution..

Comment: @TaW If you mean that you have to Paint the control yourself (and if you actually wanted to ping me and not this guy Jime :), then yes. We have to, there's no other way I know to paint the Tab headers. Of course you shouldn't paint the headers in the PaintBackground method as in that answer if you need them working. I use the `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` because it's very simple to adjust the TabControl *contour*. You just need to set the RECT bounds, send them back to `lParam` and it's done. Then, you need to decide if you want to paint using OnPaint's `e.Graphics`,  `UXTheme` or `VisuaStyleRenderer`...

Comment: @TaW These two articles: [Painting Your Own Tabs - Second Edition](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition) and [A Completely OwnerDraw TabControl](https://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm) have almost everything one needs to know about this matter (except a description on how to use `VisualStyleRenderer` to render a Tab header and its infamous pre-cooked, sticky borders. But it's not that complicated either).

Comment: Thank you all. I understood that I needed a custom control.

Comment: @Jimi could you explain? I'm not sure I understood your first comment. (I'm interested, but confused.)